# Create a Search in PHP without a database

Tags: javascript, php, search, hide, output

Creating the form is the easy part

```
<form action="mymovies.php" method="get" > 
<input type="text" size="25" onkeydown="searchq();" placeholder="Search" name="search" class="search_box fanceyInput"></form>
```

Using this script as is does not output the file when searched for. I know it's not right but can someone help me fix it?

```
    <script>
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();

    $.get("mymovies.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
        $("#output").php(output);                                                  
     });
}
    </script>
```

Currently I am pulling the filenames down from my server using,

```
$myDirectory = opendir("./movies");  // Opens directory
```

and then doing a lot of other stuff, if you care to look { [FILE](http://pastebin.com/4mJLB9ub) } but ultimately the list of movies gets printed out into a table using this,

```
 print("
    <tr class='$class'>
        <td><a href='./$namehref$name</a></td>
        <td>$mpreview</td>
        <td>$mrating</td>
        <td>$mrunningtime</td>
        <td>$thefilesize</td>
        <td>$DateAdded</td>
    </tr>");
```

So again my question is how can I change or clean up my page so when searching for a specific movie it either scrolls down, goes to, or displays the searched movie at the top of the page?

In addition to all this how can I HIDE/IGNORE files with a .php extension from showing up in the print list? It's a list of movies so they are all .mp4 but in order for me to grab the file sizes (over 2 gigs) I had to put a php page inside the movies folder. No reason for it to show in the list.

One last thing at the top of the pastebin page there are a list of other things I would like to add to this page, if someone that codes pretty easy could spend an hour with me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can set up a database but what would the advantage of me having a database be? I am uploading these movies via ftp to my local server so if I did set up the database I would need a refresher on how to get the two to connect. One thing I would need to do is have the webpage tell the database to search the server for an updated movie list. Last time I did databases was a while ago and I don't remember everything. I would be open to a generic connection with hints as to what I need to do. I'm sure I could figure that out.

Comment: Just make sure your server returns the data in a proper format such as json or xml (I'd defenitely go with json here). You'll make yourself a lot of unnecessary work trying to format your data properly when they're given in a format that is not made for working with data (like you do at the moment).

Comment: i would do a single GET request to grab the list of files, returning JSON. let javascript turn it into a sortable, searchable table: you can't update the DOM with php unless you refresh the page. jquery has plenty of plugins that do all of that for you like datatables.

Comment: the biggest advantage of a db is the creation and storage of data once, you do a lot of work for every single visitor, when you could do all that just once.

Comment: Let me see what I can do and I will get back on here later. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery for searching...

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","Scheme"];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```